# An algebraic analogue of the Bolzano-Weierstrass for formal limits?

Tags: compactness

The Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem is a very useful result in the theory of metric spaces. It states that given a compact space $X$, a sequence $(u_n) \in X^\omega$ always has a subsequence $(u_{n_k})\in X^\omega$ which is convergent.

Bolzano-Weierstrass can sometimes allow us to make a passage from a theorem being true for a dense subset of cases to being true for all cases. For instance, if we know that every Hermitian matrix that has *pairwise distinct eigenvalues* can be diagonalised using a unitary matrix, then by appealing to Bolzano-Weierstrass we may conclude that *all* Hermitian matrices can be diagonalised using unitary matrices. The compactness of the space of unitary matrices is essential here. The need to use compactness (and Bolzano-Weierstrass) stems from the fact that the unitary diagonalisation of a Hermitian matrix does not vary continuously, so we can't take the limit of a sequence, but have to pass to a convergent subsequence.

We know that the manifold $S^n$ (the $n$-sphere) is compact. But its tangent bundle $TS^n$ is not compact. But I'm wondering whether there is a substitute for compactness, and an analogue of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, that we can use for $TS^n$. This might have some connection to formal limits, formal differentiation, Zariski open sets, and other formal analogues of notions from analysis.